# Question about "staying alive"

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

Do you know the famous song named "staying alive" by Bee Gees?
I want to know how to translate the sentence.

I think there are two ways of translating this title of the song.

First, while you are staying alive (adverb phrase)
Second, staying alive is ~~ (gerund)

How can I tell the meaning of the sentence out of the two above when I meet "ing" form at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: *Staying Alive* may be the song's name  but it is not a sentence. Perhaps you could include the song lyrics in which this phrase is found. Then perhaps we would have more context in which to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the song it's the back part of a verb phrase in the progressive, with the *BE* piece omitted (along with the VP's subject) when the phrase is repeated:

> Whether you're a brother or whether you're a mother
> You'**re stayin' alive**, stayin' alive
> Feel the city breakin' and everybody shakin'
> And we**'re stayin' alive**, stayin' alive
> Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive, stayin' alive
> Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive

This sort of deletion is very common in conversation:

> Whatcha doin?
> <s>I'm</s> jus chillin
>
> What's 박용현 up to now?
> <s>He's</s> asking questions on ELL.